# How is Python's "and" Keyword Parsed in the len() Function?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Consider the following code:

```
str1 = "Hi, how are you?"
str2 = "Fine."
str3 = "Goodbye."
print len(str1 and str2 and str3)
```

The last line always prints the length of the last argument of `len()`.

Why does that happen, and how does the interpreter parse that expression?
How is it even syntactically permissible to use the `and` keyword in `len()`?

Comment: The `len` part of your question is a red herring

Comment: That gives you the length of the last string if none of them are empty. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real question is what `str1 and str2` evaluates to, or actually what `'a' and 'b'`  evaluates to. It turns out that `'a' and 'b'` evaluates to `'b'`.

Therefore in your example, `str1 and str2 and str3` evaluates to `Goodbye.` which explains why `len(str1 and str2 and str3)` is 8.

Interestingly enough, while `'a' and 'b'` is `'b'`, `'a' or 'b'` is `'a'`.

Why?

I believe it has to do with [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). 
Since `bool('a')` (or any non-empty string) is True, the Python interpreter needs to evaluate `True and True` or in our second case, `True or True`.

For optimization reasons explained in the Wikipedia page I linked to, when evaluating `True and True` the second `True` will be returned but while evaluating `True or True` the first `True` can be returned (because `True or anything` will always be `True` there is no reason to bother evaluating the second term).

In order to get your desired result you should use the `+` operator:

```
str1 = "Hi, how are you?"
str2 = "Fine."
str3 = "Goodbye."
print len(str1 + str2 + str3)
```

Comment: Just wondering myself, why doesn't `"a" and "b"` evaluate to `True`?

Comment: @SamM what do you mean *"why"*? That's what the language reference says it does: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations. Or do you mean why did the designers decide to implement that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Option #2.

Comment: @SamM it says that too: *"This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value."*

Comment: Good answer, you should add a paragraph with the real solution using concatenation

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Thanks, and I added the way to get OP's result.